# Error adding platform android: ShellCommandError: Non-zero exit from subprocess

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

What is the problem? I am trying to add android platform for my application. I were using Ionic 3.2.0 earlier. Now it's Ionic 4.0.1. I have tried to downgrade ionic back to 3.2.0, and then add platform, but it says, cordova - unknown command lol, whats have happend?

Here is the output:

```
...
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Adding cordova-plugin-file-transfer to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-filepath" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-filepath" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-filepath to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-filepath" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin com-sarriaroman-photoviewer@^1.1.18 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-geolocation to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-geolocation" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-insomnia" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-insomnia" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-insomnia to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-insomnia" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Adding cordova-plugin-firebase to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-firebase" to config.xml
Preparing Firebase on Android
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving android@~7.0.0 into config.xml file ...
[ERROR] ShellCommandError: Non-zero exit from subprocess. { name: 'ShellCommandError', code:
        'ERR_ICF_SHELL_NON_ZERO_EXIT', exitCode: 1, signal: undefined } Error

             at new BaseError
        (C:\Users\volkk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-framework\errors.js:15:23)
             at new ShellCommandError
        (C:\Users\volkk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-framework\errors.js:47:9)
             at ChildProcess.p.on
        (C:\Users\volkk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-framework\utils\shell.js:99:33)
             at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
             at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
             at ChildProcess.cp.emit
        (C:\Users\volkk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
             at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
             at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

Ionic Info:

```
C:\Users\volkk\Desktop\CargoTenderApp>ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.1 (C:\Users\volkk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v8.9.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : C:\android
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same issue today. After trying few things it got fixed. Not sure what caused this.

Can you try these steps.

First of all perform a clean npm install after removing node_modules, platforms and plugins directories. Then run the following commands.

1. Run the command.

   `ionic cordova platform remove ios --save`
2. Run the command

   `ionic cordova platform remove android --save`
3. Add iOS platform back

   `ionic cordova platform add ios --save`
4. Add Android Platform back

   `ionic cordova platform add android --save`

Also try updating @ionic/app-scripts to version `3.1.11`

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem. Just before throwing this error I had:

```
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-facebook4" from config.xml
```

Reference to this package exists in `package.json` and `config.xml` and points to github repo.

Since the reference is already in `config.xml` removing it from `package.json` did the trick.

```
"cordova-plugin-facebook4": "git+https://github.com/Bilbayt/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git",
```

It only happens on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
npm i -g cordova
```

cordova not has been instaled into my machine